# Using jquery: Show an ajax-loading gif for each image being loaded until the that indivisual image is loaded fully

Tags: jquery

Using jquery how to show a loading gif until a image is completely loaded and then remove the loading gif and show the actual image. This should happen independently on all images inside the page. Here is an example:

http://jwt.com/

Here is my attempt which does not seem to work:

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail"><a href="#" class="boxImage ajaxloader"><img src="...image-one..." /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail"><a href="#" class="boxImage ajaxloader"><img src="...image-two..." /></a></div>
<div class="thumbnail"><a href="#" class="boxImage ajaxloader"><img src="...image-three..." /></a></div>
```

CSS

```
.ajaxloader{ background: transparent url(..ajax-loader.gif...) no-repeat scroll center center;
```

JS

```
    $('a.boxImage img').one("load", function(){
         $(this).parent().removeClass('ajax-loader');
     }).each(function(){
         //covering the case images loading from cache
         if(this.complete){
            $(this).trigger("load");
            $(this).parent().removeClass('ajax-loader');
         }
    });
```

Another question... does the above method (say, after fixing the issue) allow only one image to load at a time or does it allow the browser to make multiple requests for images and load as many as it can in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but this is a better version of what you already have:

```
$('a.boxImage img').on("load", function(){//Note: .on() not .one()
     $(this).parent().removeClass('ajax-loader');
 }).each(function(){
     //covering the case images loading from cache
     if(this.complete){
        $(this).trigger("load");
        //No need to repeat the code; triggering the load handler does the job.
     }
});
```

You will probably have an issue with browsers (subject to settings) displaying an image placeholder (partially) over the loading animation. For this reason it's better to use an additional `<img>` element (one per thumbnail). Start with the loading animation showing and the real image hidden, then when the real image's load event fire, hide the animation and show the real image.

```
$('a.boxImage img.real').on("load", function(){
    $(this).show().siblings('img.loading').hide();
 }).each(function(){
     //covering the case images loading from cache
     if(this.complete){
        $(this).trigger("load");
     }
});
```

You also need to ensure that the container and/or the loading image is sized to the same size as the thumbnail such that there's no change of size when the switch occurs. You may well do this already in CSS that I can't see.